# CryptLib decryption returns wrong value

Tags: swift, encryption, swift3, cryptography

I am using [Cross-Platform-AES](https://github.com/skavinvarnan/Cross-Platform-AES) for my AES encryption/decryption within my swift app. My encryption is working fine. But when I try to decrypt the service returns value it doesn't give me the correct result. Here how I am doing decryption.

```
public func decryptStrings(text:String)->String{

    let hashKey=cryptoLib.sha256(key, length: 31)
    let decryptedData = cryptoLib.decrypt(text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8), key: hashKey, iv: iv)
    let decryptedString=decryptedData?.base64EncodedString()
    print("decryptedString \(decryptedString! as String)")
    return decryptedString!

}
```

Please explain me how can I decrypt this in correct way.
Thanks

**ENCRYPTION**

```
public func base64Convertion (secretcode:String)->String
{


    let hashKey=cryptoLib.sha256(key, length: 31)
    let encryptedData=cryptoLib.encrypt(secretcode.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8), key: hashKey, iv: iv)
    let encryptedString=encryptedData?.base64EncodedString()
    print("encryptedString \(encryptedString! as String)")


    return encryptedString!

}
```

Comment: Please show also how you encrypt and let us know an example input.

Comment: You should *decode* the Base64 encoded string *before* decrypting the data.

Comment: @MartinR I added this line before the decrypt let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: text, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions()) but still doesnt give the correct valut

Comment: Thanks It's working now

Comment: @Randi Can you show the detail how it worked for you. I am still getting the issue with decryption

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the  Decryption method in this way

```
    public func decryptStrings(text:String)->String{

    let hashKey=cryptoLib.sha256(key, length: 31)
    let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: text, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions())
    let decryptedData = cryptoLib.decrypt(decodedData, key: hashKey, iv: iv)
    let decryptedString=String(data: decryptedData!,encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)
    print("decryptedString \(decryptedString!)")
    return decryptedString!

}
```